# How to redirect http to https python http.server

Tags: python, http, https, server, httpserver

How can I redirect HTTP to HTTPS by default?

For example, if I type example_address.com I would like to get https://example_address.com

My code is below

```
def run(server_class=HTTPServerV6, handler_class=Server, port=443):
    server_address = ('::', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='./secret_private_key.pem', server_side=True)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you're hosting an actual website with an https endpoint and a certificate, you should use an actual server.

Comment: Can you please explain your thought? When I am connecting to the server, I have to write https. So, my desire is to avoid that process.

Comment: Let me know if you want to add .htaacess url redirect rule ??  Basically it will redirect user to https version whenever they open any url in http version.

Comment: I cannot find how to use htacces in python. My server uses only python.

Answer (score 2):

You could try running another server in **port 80** and redirecting its requests to your https server.

Something like this:

```
def runHTTP(server_class=HTTPServerV6, handler_class=Server, port=80):
server_address = ('::', port)
httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
httpd.send_response(301)
httpd.send_header('Location','https://www.yourserver.com')
httpd.end_headers()
```

Comment: This approach has its place. I have a piece of stand alone software that has it's own webserver embedded on 443. This provides a very simple redirect w/o having to stand up nginx or apache.